# remove puppet and chef-client from ubuntu 14.04? is it safe?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I saw that `puppet` and `chef-client` are installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and that they are started automatically at OS boot.

I do not use them, I use Ansible.

Is it safe to remove them? What is the safest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If neither are being used for anything, there should be no problem with removing them.

In fact, you can do it in ansible:

```
# Remove "chef-client" package
- apt: name=chef-client state=absent
# Remove "puppet" package
- apt: name=puppet state=absent
# Stop Puppet service
- service: name=puppet state=stopped enabled=no
# Stop Chef service
- service: name=chef state=stopped enabled=no
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get purge chef-client puppet

Note: The above command will completely remove chef-client and puppet packages from your machine and also the associated configuration files.